# How to remove curved corners from a blog post in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am stuck with removing the curved corner from the image on blog posts on Wordpress.

https://www.marriedin.co.uk/guides/

I have managed to remove the bottom corner  with the following

```
  .content-box {
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Just can't workout how to remove the curve on the top corner of the image. You can see that the container itself has no curved corner but the image still has one.

thanks

Comment: `.type-post .entry-cover.has-image { border-radius: 0; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.type-post .entry-cover.has-image {
 border-radius: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That's brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the element shows that classes .*type-post*, .*entry-cover* and .*has-image* define the corner radius specifically. Try to define:

```
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
```

To anyone who is not aware, it's possible to test CSS changes directly on the browser inspector. Doing so can save a lot of time figuring out from what element a problem comes from and helps testing out possible changes.

Answer (score 0):

The child element of the `<article>` tag is what's imposing those rounded corners on the image.

Try adding the following:

```
.type-post .entry-cover.has-image, .type-post .has-image.entry-cover--home, .type-post .has-image.listing-cover{
  border-radius:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The container for your image has top-left and top-right border radius set. It's in `style.min.css`:

```
.type-post .entry-cover.has-image, .type-post .has-image.entry-cover--home, .type-post .has-image.listing-cover {
    border-top-left-radius: 4px; /* change to 0px */
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

If you find this bit of markup, and change the 4px to 0px you will lose the rounded edges

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you still have `border-top-left-radius` and `border-top-right-radius` set to 4px.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your custom css:

```
.content-box {
    border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

The `!important`option will override any other stylesheet applying style to that class.

Also, make sure to refresh your browser properly to reflect the changes in your browser, that may have cached data. If you use Chrome, use `ctrl`+`F5` or open an incognito window.

Comment: Actually, you were trying to edit the wrong class. The right one was .entry-cover .has-image. Try to set that to the above as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
.type-post .entry-cover.has-image, .type-post .has-image.entry-cover--home, .type-post .has-image.listing-cover {
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it

```
.type-post .entry-cover.has-image {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```